# Horizontal align cells in excel from vb6?

Tags: excel, vb6, vba

I'm working in vb6 and I need to align an excel cell to center. after that(or before whichever works) I need to merge a range of cells including the one that is centered.
what I am trying to use right now is this code,

```
oSheet.range("A1:N1").Merge
oSheet.range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

where oSheet is the excel sheet and xlCenter should be a constant of excel. the problem i am facing is that when i run this code it gives me an error saying that it is unable to set the HorizontalAlignment property of the Range class. this is error 1004. when i go to debug the program and put the mouse over `xlCenter` it says `xlCenter = empty`.

Comment: You can get the value of `xlCenter` from the object browser in the Excel VB editor.  Unless your VB project has a reference to the Excel object library it's not going to know what xlCenter is, so you need to either define it as a constant in your VB code, or replace it with the actual value.

Comment: yes that worked, thanks for pointing that out i hadnt thought of it. and to anyone stumbling on this question the value for xlCenter is &HFFFFEFF4

Comment: also @TimWilliams please write an answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your VB project has a reference to the Excel object library it's not going to know what `xlCenter` is, so you will need to either:

- define it as a constant in your VB code

or

- replace it with the actual value

You can get the value of xlCenter from the object browser in the Excel VB editor.